# upgrade from version .net 4.7 to 4.8

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have a project in .net framework 4.7 and now I have to upgrade to 4.8 for administrative reasons.

I went to check if I have version 4.8 but I was surprised that I do not have version 4.7 installed so I wonder how can version 4.7 run if it is not installed?

example change version from vs:

[image]

but when checking in my folders I don't see only version 4.0
[image]

I install it in IIS and it works perfectly. How is it possible that it works correctly with version 4.7 or 4.8 when I don't see version 4.7 or 4.8 anywhere on the server?

Comment: 4.7 and 4.8 both still use the 4.0 runtime, and simply add compiler features and security patches on top of it. Similarly, 2.0 all the up through the 3.5 era all used the 2.0 runtime.

Comment: It's just a target framework, the one that actually runs will be whatever is installed (this only applies to major version numbers)